# MVC 4 Restrict all actions/controllers unless ADMIN or role/user allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, authorization

I'm working on a MVC 4 web application, on VS 2010. What I am trying to do is:

1. Restrict access to all users unless you are SUPERADMIN automatically (login in using form authentication)
2. If the action/controller states you that a specific roles can have access then it gives them access. For example:

   ```
   [AuthorizeFor(Roles = "REVIEWER")]
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
   ```

   In the case above, only users with roles SUPERADMIN OR REVIEWER can access this action.
3. I will also be using WEBAPI so I can push content to third parties, and so should be accessible by anyone, but they will need to authenticate via url paramenter with hmac. For example: http://example.com/api/feed/1?appid=BLAH&timestamp=BLAH&hmac=BLAH. In short, the API section of the site should not be using the same authentication as the rest of it.

How would I set this up?

I am building a content management system for internal use here at my job, and the API will supply the data that we enter in to third party websites/vendors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add to the GlobalFilterCollection in App_Start/FilterConfig.cs:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        // Applies an Authorize Attribute to each controller so that by default all SUPERADMINS have access you could then add [Authorize(Roles = "REVIEWER"] to individual items.
        filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute() { Roles = "SUPERADMIN" });
    }
}
```

In the WebAPI controller you could use the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the WebAPI Controllers and handle the auth yourself by checking the hmac param.